# Does google chrome app development allow you to add html and javascript to the locally stored files, depending on user

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to create a web app platform that runs locally on the users computer.
I am considering using google chrome's app process to make this work.

I am having trouble understanding, wether google will let me do this. so the user would have to download the main chrome app , which contains the base html and javascript code, and within the app be able to download and store locally with in the app new html and js code.

So in other words I want to create an app that allows users to download and install apps from my own app store, and have them run within the chrome app.

Does google chrome app development allow this?
if not what are my alternatives for creating an app that needs to run on a browser storing all files locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download HTML and CSS as much as you want and then use JavaScript to modify the DOM accordingly. It's not set up as any kind of system that lets you substitute pages, and there's no navigation within the app (using A elements), but you are free to modify the DOM.

There's no way to add any JavaScript to what's initially in the app, as eval and the other code-executing functions are disabled. You can certainly add SCRIPT elements to the DOM, but the files they reference have to have been part of the app at the time it was installed.

Having said all that, you can implement the app as an interpreter for some language and then download programs written in that language. It's just that none of the code can be direct Chrome App code, nor can any code you download (regardless of language) make direct Chrome API calls.

Comment: Thank you so much I was going in circles trying to understand this, and I see that with this whole DOM , there could potentially be a work around. Where I have the javascript pull a txt file with javascript code and have it placed like a script into a pre-emptied html page.

Comment: That works fine provided the text file referenced by the SCRIPT tag is inside the Chrome App (in the same directory as the manifest.json file, or a subdirectory).

Comment: can I grab the text from a server? or will the chrome app block this?

Comment: The file referenced by the SCRIPT tag must be inside the app. JavaScript in the SCRIPT element or anywhere else in the HTML is disallowed.

Comment: So in other words I can not use <script> </script> within a html file?

Comment: You can, but not with JavaScript directly in the HTML, only via the SRC attribute of the SCRIPT tag. You can't have JavaScript anywhere else, either, such as in an ONCLICK attribute of a button. To repeat what I said: JavaScript code can NEVER directly appear ANYWHERE in an HTML file, nor can it be added to the DOM dynamically. This and other restrictions are well documented here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Thank you Marc, I am opting out to use tidesdk instead, you should look into it pretty cool stuff! Having a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the HTML5 Filesystem API? You can fetch a file and reference it later. You also need the add the "unlimitedStorage" permission to manifest.json.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/